# Dojo Tooltip with multiple labels

Tags: dojo

I am new in Dojo and trying to find some features availability in Dojo. Please let me know if we can have multiple labels in Dojo tooltip widget.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by multiple labels. The Tooltip label is used as an innerHTML, so it can contain HTML. I've used a  inside of a label. Maybe you can use a list or other tags.

Also, you can change the Tooltip's label programmatically with:

myToolTip.set("label", "My New Label");